# `objects.get(...)` does not work as expected

Tags: django-models, neo4django

I'm trying to get an object from my **neo4j** database using **neo4django**

```
>>> # There is a single Person object in the database, so I get a value
>>> slug=Person.objects.get().name_slug
>>> print(slug)
doe-john
>>> # ok, it's there
>>> p=Person.objects.get(name_slug=slug)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/[...]/src/neo4django/neo4django/db/models/manager.py", line 37, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 366, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Person matching query does not exist.
>>> p=Person.objects.get(name_slug__exact=slug)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/[...]/src/neo4django/neo4django/db/models/manager.py", line 37, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 366, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Person matching query does not exist.
```

The error message is not sensible. I just received the queried string from the very field, so there **must** be a match. Any ideas? Or did I stumble upon a bug?

This is really strange, as it works with the other properties, but not with `name_slug`:

```
>>> Person.objects.get(surname='Doe')
<Person: Person object>
>>> Person.objects.get(given_name='John')
<Person: Person object>
>>> Person.objects.get(name_slug='john-doe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/[...]/src/neo4django/neo4django/db/models/manager.py", line 37, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 366, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: Person matching query does not exist.
>>> print( p.surname, p.given_name, p.name_slug )
(u'Doe', u'John', u'john-doe')
```

My model is defined as such:

```
class Person(models.NodeModel):
    surname = models.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    given_name = models.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    name_slug = models.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```

So the only difference is that it's not `required`, but that should make no difference, in my understanding of the documentation.

Comment: Or if not the query log (I'm not sure whether Neo4j has one), using django-debug-toolbar with the Neo4j REST panel might help.

Comment: Is this against neo4django master or the version on PyPi?

Comment: It is against a `master` of neo4django, though I'm not sure when I last updated. (though not older than a month)., and I'm on neo4j 1.8.2, because recently the `readme.rst` still stated that it was tested against 1.8-1.9RC -- I see that was updated 9 days ago to include 1.9 (stable).

Comment: I'll update and report back!

Comment: I updated to `neo4j 1.9` (which took half a day, because it needs Java 7, for that I had to update to Mountain Lion, and had to fiddle around to get Java 7 work properly). Also using git clone from yesterday (Sunday).

Comment: @MattLuongo: This is **crazy**! In my original django app the situation pertains EXACTLY as described above. However, when I create a`test_models.py` similar to yours, but actually using a copy-paste from my app's model, it _does_ work upon the same database. I am really clueless! Shall I set up a gist?

Comment: I guess so- that's pretty odd. Let's see it.

Comment: @MattLuongo: Added Gist (with hopefully helpful comments) at https://gist.github.com/szabi/5802873 — the strange behaviour persists and is demonstrated and documented by the Gist. It might seem to be some unexpected model dependency issues, as the complete copy shows the same weird behaviour, but separating out the `Person` model works; but I really cannot explain how they could have been introduced into either `neo4j` or `neo4django`.

Comment: @MattLuongo: Did you have a chance to have a look? I can provide my neo4j `data` directory as well, if necessary.

Comment: Sorry! I was taken away from work unexpectedly. I'm checking it out now.

Comment: Your data dir would be super handy. I have a feeling this has to do with a strange indexing case.

Comment: Apparently this has to do with this issue already raised on Github https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/214 and which I can also verify

Comment: @nikolasd "already" is good... the original post and the resulting discussion evolved in June 2013. The issue on github was raised *later*, in October 2013. -- Thanks for the pointers to the issue (definitely a useful link for reference), but calling "already" as if the question did not use enough research effort is a bit unfair.

Comment: @ASz you are right! I just added the comment as a reference for future users, since there is no an accepted answer on this question.

Comment: @nikolasd anyway, with version numbers progressing rapidly I don't have the leisure to see if this nearly year-old setup could be fixed up, just to have an answer fixed up. Though if I come around to see if the current versions work as expected, that could be added as an acceptable answer (i.e. "update to current version, it's fixed there").

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate this using neo4django master, on Neo4j 1.9.

I created a test_models.py

```
from neo4django.db import models

class Person(models.NodeModel):
    class Meta:
        # since test_models isn't in an app
        app_label='test'
    surname = models.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    given_name = models.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    name_slug = models.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```

and then ran

```
>>> from test_models import Person
>>> john = Person.objects.create(surname=u'Doe', given_name=u'John', name_slug=u'john-doe')
>>> Person.objects.get(name_slug='john-doe')
<Person: Person object>
>>> john == Person.objects.get(name_slug='john-doe')
True
>>> jane = Person.objects.create(surname=u'Doe', given_name=u'Jane', name_slug=u'jane-doe')
>>> jane == Person.objects.get(name_slug='jane-doe')
True
>>> jane == Person.objects.get(given_name='Jane', surname='Doe')
True
```

Thoughts?