# Node properties not created when using neo4django

Tags: django, django-models, neo4j, neo4django

I have a `Model` in `django` created with `neo4django`.

```
class Person(models.NodeModel):
    """
    Persons of a Company
    """
    email = models.EmailProperty(required=True, unique=True, indexed=True,
                                 name=_(u'email'),
                                 verbose_name=_(u'person email address'),
                                 help_text=_(u'bla bla bla some help text'))
    full_name = models.StringProperty(name=_(u'Person full name'))

    # Neo4J Relationships
    role = models.Relationship(Role, rel_type='has_role',
                                     direction='Outgoing',
                                     related_name='persons')
    company = models.Relationship(Company, rel_type='works_to',
                                           direction='Outgoing',
                                           related_name='employees')
```

I try on the django shell

```
>>> p = Person.objects.create(email=u'email@company.com')
>>> p.id
6
>>> Person.objects.get(id='6')
<Person: Person object>
>>> Person.objects.get(email=u'email@company.com')
Traceback [bla bla bla]
[...]
DoesNotExist: Person matching query does not exist.
>>>
```

I also checked on the `Neo4J` web interface and I see the created node, but without any properties!

This problem looks like the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17126274/objects-get-does-not-work-as-expected) but I am not sure if this is the same issue.

I have `Django 1.4.5` and `Neo4J 1.8.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt thanks a lot for your recommendation. I always run the master git version.

I upgraded to `Django 1.5.1` and the problem disappeared. I still run the 1.8.2 version of Neo4J.

**UPDATE**

Trying to figure it out, I reverted back to `Django 1.4.5` and after some research, I discovered, that the problem was actually because of the `name` attribute on the node properties.

So if I change this

```
full_name = models.StringProperty(name=_(u'Person full name'))
```

to this

```
full_name = models.StringProperty(verbose_name=_(u'Person full name'))
```

or this

```
full_name = models.StringProperty()
```

then everything works as expected.

Actually the `name` issue exists even if you upgrade to `Django 1.5.1` so I guess there is some issue creating the properties when having a name attribute in it.

Comment: Wow- I'm surprised this works, especially since we don't officially support 1.5. Awesome.

Comment: It works, but there are some minor glitches, that I will report them here or on github (wherever you suggest) and probably be able to contribute any updates to the project.

Comment: I'd definitely report those on GitHub. A roadmap of the issues you run into would really speed up official support (https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/143).

Answer (score 0):

What version of neo4django are you using? I'd suggest trying the same code with neo4django master off Github (`pip install -e git+https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django#egg=neo4django-dev`).